# 240 V split-phase to power 12 VDC fans and lights

Tags: circuit-design, transformer, led-driver, phase

Im re-powering an model-81 Powermatic bandsaw with a 3 HP Leeson DC motor (14 A max. draw) and a KBCC-255 motor drive (fused @ 15 A). I want to put some fans to cool the DC drive heatsink and LED pucks in the enclosure for work surface lighting. Fans 420 mA each, 1 light @ 170 mA.

I plan to wire the machine with a neutral.

1. Would pulling 120 V (fused @ 1 A) from one leg to power a [MeanWell SE-100](http://d114hh0cykhyb0.cloudfront.net/pdfs/SE-100.PDF) power be fine, similar to how a stove is wired?
2. Running an isolation transformer 2x-120 primary 1x-120 secondary with neutral to prevent overcurrent on 12 V power supply, and unbalanced load on 20 A double pole breaker? Also ISK transformer on 12 V PSU transformer acceptable?
3. Would using both 120 V legs (no neutral) be an acceptable circuit for the PSU-max input 264 Vwith neutral.
4. Breadboard ISO transformer-rectifier-capacitor-regulator in place of the SE-100.

Location: rural FL, US No 3-phase

https://kb.samsara.com/hc/en-us/articles/216671538-What-is-Split-Phase-Single-phase-120-240-

Answer (score 1):

The power supply will operate fine from 240VAC. I don't see any reason to involve the neutral.

You must have a ground for safety, of course.

Buying a supply makes more sense to me than trying to build a linear regulated supply for several amperes but it's certainly feasible to make a DC supply then regulate it down (with a heatsink or a SMPS module). Mains frequency transformers are large and expensive and heavy for shipping so unless you have an appropriate one in your junk bin it probably doesn't make sense.

Make sure that metal swarf etc. cannot get into the supply or you'll have a problem and pay attention to the application notes. Also, make sure it's not a counterfeit, for safety reasons.

Note: If you are asking questions that edge on electrical codes etc. as opposed to circuit design, it's better to indicate what country or countries are involved. From the 120/240 I might assume it's North America.

Comment: Thanks. Yup North America. Im with you on the swarth, box for Motor Drive & SMPS will draw air from the body of the machine which also has built in dust/swarth collection

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJdBO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use your SMPS rated up tp 264VAC to mid-phase voltage. Choose two phases of your choice and connect to SPMS's contacts L and N. Connect the protection earth (PE) as well. Use a magnetic circuit breaker of some 4A, or what is recommended by SMPS manual. Use a breaker with D characteristics, because of large inrush current. The circuit breaker is used to protect your wires from melting in case of SMPS failure, so it has no big importance if you choose 2A, 4A or 10A ,just match it to your connecting wires cross section.

The motor circuit section shall be equipped with motor protection device with matching current rating, these devices have a adjusting knob to set the current rating.

[image]

[image]